# Why is my array not found when it is so there?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

My jdk compiler keeps telling me that my array, called nums, is not found when it is so there!  What gives?  Please forgive my ignorance; I am just learning.  Anyway, my code is listed below.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
            nums[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("Unsorted array: " + Arrays.toString(nums));
        sort();
        System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
    
    public static void sort() {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (nums[j] > nums[j+1]) {
                    temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[j+1];
                    nums[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it doesn't. You declared it scoped to `main`, yet you're trying to use it inside `sort` without having passed it along.

Comment: Because `num` only exist inside `main`. Other methods do not automatically have access to local variables. You can pass the variable as argument, or you can make it a field, or …

Comment: OMG, I did not see that I declared it inside main!  Now I know why programming is done in groups on the job.  It always takes another pair of eyes to find your mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

`nums` is not visible outside of the method in which it was defined (`main`). Pass it as an argument to `sort` instead.

Change the signature of `sort` to accept an array parameter:

```java
public static void sort(int[] nums)
```

Pass `nums` to `sort` in `main`:

```java
sort(nums);
```